# Are websocket subprotocols like WAMP, STOMP, etc. compatible with each other?

Tags: java, websocket, messaging, stomp

I am looking to leverage WebSockets. I will expose the WebSockets and different client applications will be able to listen to notifications via these WebSockets.

I am planning to use STOMP, but my clients have different preferences as their applications are already using different sub-protocols. I was wondering if there is any **cross support** available from one subprotocol to another?

Comment: What is WAMP in this context?

Comment: WAMP is an open standard WebSocket subprotocol. https://wamp-proto.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no. WAMP and STOMP are not compatible with each other.

The [STOMP](https://stomp.github.io/) specification has no "cross support" for anything else. In fact, I've never heard of any widely-used messaging protocol with "cross support" for anything else.

That said, many message brokers support multiple messaging protocols (e.g. ActiveMQ supports STOMP, AMQP, MQTT - all of which can be used over WebSockets) so you can send messages with one protocol and consume them with another protocol. However, I don't know of any widely-used message brokers which support WAMP.

Comment: so you are suggesting that the sender and receiver connected to ActiveMQ can have different protocols. can you please share some documents which can describe its functioning?

Comment: Regarding ActiveMQ documentation [this](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/protocols-interoperability.html) is probably a good place to start.